# Use the same brackets or parenthesis as equations in an empty style environment

Tags: environments, theorems

I have the following in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[overload, ntheorem]{empheq}
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}
\newtagform{brackets}{[}{]}
\usetagform{brackets}
```

Further, I also have

```
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape}\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremsymbol{}
\newtheorem{optional}{}
```

So now I can make an empty environment which takes an optional argument like `\begin{optional}[$H_2$]`. This works but I get to see (H_2) while I would like to see [H_2]. How do I change this? It would be perfect if I could access the `mathtools` command that gives me the left bracket and the right bracket so I don't have to change it in multiple places if I would want to change it (I could of course define a new command for the left and right bracket but that feels like an ugly hack!).

I forgot to mention that if I give it a label, then refering to it should give the optional argument. Maybe there is a better solution to this problem. I have also tried an equation with `\tag` but `\text` doesn't do automatic line breaks.

Thanks for the suggestion. I fixed it like this, but I don't know if it is a good way:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{optional}[1][Hypothesis]{
  \par\noindent \text{[#1]}
  \def\@currentlabel{[#1]}
}{\\}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be a better idea if you provide a full minimal example, for those not knowing it is not obvious that you a using `ntheorem`. As for you question. You will need to define an alternative theoremstyle, as the braces are hardwired inside it.

Here is the default for `nonumberplain`

```
\newtheoremstyle{nonumberplain}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip \labelsep ##1\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
```

to make it work you will need something like

```
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mynonumberplain}%
 {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]}%
 {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip \labelsep ##1\ {[##3]}\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
```

(since we are already inside a pair of `[]`'s we need to protect it with a pair of `{}`'s)

For your second question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{brackets}{[}{]}
\usetagform{brackets}
\makeatletter
\let\xxx\tagform@
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\xxx{4}
\end{document}
```

you can use `\tagform@` inside the `mynonumberplain` definition, but it has to come `after` the `\usetagform{brackets}`. The `xxx` is just to get rid of the @

As for the last question

```
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mynonumberplain}%
 {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]}%
 {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip \labelsep ##1\ {[##3]}\theorem@separator]
 \def\@currentlabel{##3}}
\makeatother
```

the trick here is that we need the `\@currentlabel` outside the `\item[...]`, because it forms a local group, and thus would never get outside, unless we make it global, and that might not be a good idea.

Comment: I have added that I use `ntheorem`. Do you have a suggestion for my other comments? The label and using the brackets as I defined them using `mathtools`.

Comment: @Jonas: was this better?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about it how I can use your suggestions. About the label I think I need to do something like `\def\@currentlabel{#1}` where `#1` refers to the optional argument. I wonder if I can do that using `ntheorem`.

Comment: @jonas: you can but you need to be a bit devious, see my edit.